# Google Plus iOS SDK not refreshing expired token

Tags: ios, iphone, sdk, token

I have a problem, which might have a so simple solution, that I am not able to see it.

I installed the Google Plus iOS SDK into my app, and got my app running with Google very nice.

[Google Plus iOS SDK](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/)

BUT, after one hour, the token is expiring, and I don't find a way to renew it.

```
- (void)renewGoogleToken {
    GPPSignIn *gppSignIn                        = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
    gppSignIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser         = YES;
    gppSignIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail        = YES;
    gppSignIn.clientID                          = [DSUtils getGoogleClientID];
    gppSignIn.scopes                            = @[@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login",
                                                @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"];
    gppSignIn.delegate                          = self;

    BOOL success                                = [gppSignIn trySilentAuthentication];  }
```

I call this method initially, when I want to login with Google+. After one hour, when token is about to expire, I call this method again, but I receive same token, which is about to expire.

Anybody can help me please? I searched intensely on google, and could not find a solution. The SDK Docs doesn't say anything about renewing, which is strange. Is token refreshed automatically?

Please help, 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The object you get back is a `GTMOAuth2Authentication`. If being used in a regular Google service request, it should automatically be refreshed automatically if needed. However, if you need to force a refresh you can request authorization of a nil request:

```
[auth authorizeRequest:nil
          delegate:self     
 didFinishSelector:@selector(authentication:request:finishedWithError:)];
```

Or with blocks

```
[auth authorizeRequest:nil 
 completionHandler:^(NSError *error) { //...
}];
```

Comment: Thanks Ian. Today I noticed that now, if I call trySilentAuthentication, it does generate a new token. I am 100% sure this didn't work some days before. Do you know of such issue being reported these days to google? Seems like it just started working, I am pretty sure I didn't do anything different than days ago.

Comment: May have been a problem with the auth servers - I don't know of one specifically, but they do happen!

Comment: I unaccepted the answer, because it's not working. I do receive a new token, if I terminate the app, and restart with calling trySilentAuthentication. But this also fails sometimes. However, I can't request user to terminate the app each hours. This is crazyness. Nobody at  google is aware of this issue?

Comment: And calling authorizeRequest is not solving the problems, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you try creating a minimal sample that reproduces the problem? It sounds like something odd is going on. The authorizing code is pretty straightforward - if the token has expired, it will fetch a new one. If you're seeing a bug we need to get much more specific about what exactly the failure you're seeing. In the authorizeRequest callback, debug the auth object and look at the actual access token. You can drop it into the token info endpoint to get information about it: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=