# GPPSignIn error invalid_grant / Token has been revoked

Tags: ios, iphone, google-plus, google-plus-signin

Following this question:
[GPP iOS not refreshing token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29720107/google-plus-ios-sdk-not-refreshing-expired-token)

So I correctly receive refresh token, if I use the app for some time. The problem is that if I put the app in background for some hours (more than 3-4 hours as I noticed), next time when I `trySilentAuthentication`, it returns following error:

```
Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 
"The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus error 400.)" 
UserInfo=0x7feefbfa4cd0 {  
                         json={ error = "invalid_grant"; 
                         "error_description" = "Token has been revoked."; }
```

I must specify that nobody manually revoked the token or anything else done manually.

What's even more strange is that sometimes after receiving this error, if I terminate the app, and then open it again and run `trySilentAuthentication`, it's working, and a new token is correctly generated, though sometimes won't work.

Is there anything else I need to do, like showing the consent screen again? This would be much unpleasant for user, to see that screen each day.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to post some code before anyone can help you debug this.   How often are you using your refresh token?

Comment: It's exactly the code you see in the linked on top of my question, however here is the link again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29720107/google-plus-ios-sdk-not-refreshing-expired-token

Comment: As for "how often": normally, I call trySilentAuthentication each time user opens the app. And works fine, no matter how many times I open the app. But if more hours pass, next time it just won't refresh the token, instead will throw the above error. I don't see anything in documentation to help me with this. Having so many problems with these tokens, and documentation doesn't help at all.

Comment: As long as the access token is valid you should not be getting a new one with the refresh token,  the access token is valid for about an hour.  I am wondering if you are requesting to many access tokens from the server is causing it to shut you down. I have never seen this error before. Token revoke normally means that the user when into there Google settings and removed your access,  but you said that this is not the case.

Comment: Manually revoked token is definitely not the case. This is an iOS app. Do you know how often should I call trySilentAuthentication? And I doubt this to be because of requesting tokens too often. Because I can ask many many times, no problem, but after a pause of some hours, I receive the error above. Right now, I didn't call trySilentAuthentication since 3 days ago, and when called first time today, received error.

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741263/trysilentauthentication-without-google-button

Comment: Thanks, I already read that thread, and everywhere I am calling [GPPSignIn sharedInstance]. So it should work, right?